# Custom circular NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to implement a custom circular slider which uses images to draw the dial and the knob. For this purpose I have subclassed `NSSliderCell` and overridden the `drawBarInside` and `drawKnob` methods.
Now, if I leave the slider type as default (horizontal), my drawing functions are called and images are drawn in stead of the default bar and knob (of course it looks all wrong since images are made for a circular slider, but they are there). But as soon as I change the slider type to circular (either in IB or by setting `self.sliderType = NSCircularSlider;` in my slider cell) those two methods are never called and my images are not drawn (only the standard dial is created).
Am I forgetting something here, or can circular sliders not be customized at all?

Here is my code:
`DialSliderCell` is a subclass of `NSSliderCell` and is initiated and set in a class called `DialSlider` which is a subclass of `NSSlider` (this class does nothing else at the time).

```
@implementation DialSliderCell

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dialImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dial"];
        knobImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dialKnob"];
        self.sliderType = NSCircularSlider;
    }
    NSLog(@"init");
    return self;
}

- (void)drawKnob:(NSRect)knobRect {
    knobRect.size = knobImage.size;
    [knobImage drawInRect:knobRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    NSLog(@"drawKnob");
}

- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)aRect flipped:(BOOL)flipped {
    [dialImage drawInRect:aRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    NSLog(@"drawBarInside");
}

@end
```

Comment: Just a short note to anyone copying this code: This is only correct when using ARC. Otherwise you need to retain the images you get from -imageNamed: when you put them in the dialImage/knobImage instance variables.

Comment: Correct. The code was written in an ARC enviroment so no retain/release is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by overriding the `drawInteriorWithFrame` method. The solution is based on the original method. I just removed anything not related to circular sliders, removed the original graphics and added my own. The geometry is almost entirely original.

```
- (void) drawInteriorWithFrame: (NSRect)cellFrame inView: (NSView*)controlView
{
    cellFrame = [self drawingRectForBounds: cellFrame];
    _trackRect = cellFrame;

    NSPoint knobCenter;
    NSPoint point;
    float fraction, angle, radius;

    knobCenter = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(cellFrame), NSMidY(cellFrame));

    [dialImage drawInRect:cellFrame fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    int knobDiameter = knobImage.size.width;
    int knobRadius = knobDiameter / 2;
    fraction = ([self floatValue] - [self minValue]) / ([self maxValue] - [self minValue]);
    angle = (fraction * (2.0 * M_PI)) - (M_PI / 2.0);
    radius = (cellFrame.size.height / 2) - knobDiameter;
    point = NSMakePoint((radius * cos(angle)) + knobCenter.x,
                    (radius * sin(angle)) + knobCenter.y);

    NSRect dotRect;
    dotRect.origin.x = point.x - knobRadius;
    dotRect.origin.y = point.y - knobRadius;
    dotRect.size = knobImage.size;
    [knobImage drawInRect:dotRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
}
```

The size of the `cellFrame`rectangle is set to the size of the `dialImage`image.

Notice that the method above doesn't seem to get called automatically so I also had to override the `drawWithFrame` method and make it call `drawInteriorWithFrame`:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I noticed that the image draws upside-down, so you'll want to use `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:` to display the image in the correct orientation.

Comment: Also, *you cannot set _trackRect* if you're submitting your app to the App Store, since apparently setting that property is considered using a private API.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is that you are not overriding the all the designated initialisers

from the docs...

> Designated Initializers. When subclassing NSCell you must implement all
>   of the designated initializers. Those methods are: init,
>   initWithCoder:, initTextCell:, and initImageCell:.

Probably one of the other 3 is called for a circular slider.

Comment: Hi Warren. Actually I am, but I chose not to include them here for simplicity. Anyway, as I stated, the `DialSliderCell` is created manually in `DialSlider` so I am quite sure which init method is being used :) But if I set the class of my slider cell in IB then it uses `initWithCoder`which makes no difference to my problem.

Comment: When your slider is unarchived from the XIB, it unarchives both the view and the cell. That means to make it use the right cell class, you need to double-click your view in the XIB so it selects the NSSliderCell and also set its custom class, not just of the NSSlider view. Are you doing that?